# Using Index method in Tuple?

Tags: python

I understand Tuple are immutable and most of the list methods don't work on Tuple. Is there a way to find the index of an element in a tuple?(Other than typecasting it into a list and checking the index)

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite see the problem:

```
>>> t = (1,2,3)
>>> t.index(2)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `index` method of `tuple` to find the index of tuple.

```
>>> t = (1,2,3,4)
>>> t.index(2)
1
```

if tuple contains repetative items then use `start` and `stop` check.

`t.index: (value, [start, [stop]])`

```
>>> t = (1,2,3,4,2)
>>> t.index(2, 2, len(t))
4
```